# SQL запрос, вывести данные из одной и той же таблицы, но с разными типами строк

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица в MySQL:

```
post_id|  meta_key        | meta_value
--------------------
63683 | _wp_attached_file | 82ed84efed3891009784847a9a1de95f.jpg
33590 | _thumbnail_id     | 63683
33590 | _sku              | VM047

63684 | _wp_attached_file | 420543735755fa8d9698f224983c1227.jpg
16927 | _thumbnail_id     | 63684 
16927 | _sku              | JD34HD

63685 | _wp_attached_file | a7d3a08965ed3d0bcceb5776027c5694.jpg
29143 | _thumbnail_id     | 63685
29143 | _sku              | DSB53DH

63686 | _wp_attached_file | f21af97efb9c4fb820c5ef7aa1de3842.jpg
33822 | _thumbnail_id     | 63686
33822 | _sku              | TYP5873BF
```

Необходимо получить таблицу такого вида

```
ID    |  AttachFile                          |ThumbId| SKU
--------------------
33590 | 82ed84efed3891009784847a9a1de95f.jpg | 63683 | VM047
16927 | 420543735755fa8d9698f224983c1227.jpg | 63684 | JD34HD
29143 | a7d3a08965ed3d0bcceb5776027c5694.jpg | 63685 | DSB53DH
33822 | f21af97efb9c4fb820c5ef7aa1de3842.jpg | 63686 | TYP5873BF
```

**Пробовал выгрузить этим кодом:**

```
select pm.post_id, pm1.meta_value _sku, pm2.meta_value _thumbnail_id, pm3.meta_value AttachFile
            from `wp_postmeta` pm
            left join `wp_postmeta` pm1 on pm1.meta_key='_sku' and pm.post_id=pm1.post_id
            left join `wp_postmeta` pm2 on pm2.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' and pm.post_id=pm2.post_id
            left join `wp_postmeta` pm3 on pm3.meta_key='_wp_attached_file' and pm.post_id=pm2.meta_value
```

Получился такой результат:

```
ID    |  AttachFile |ThumbId| SKU
--------------------
33590 |             | 63683 | VM047
33590 |             | 63683 | VM047
33590 |             | 63683 | VM047
16927 |             | 63684 | JD34HD
16927 |             | 63684 | JD34HD
16927 |             | 63684 | JD34HD
29143 |             | 63685 | DSB53DH
29143 |             | 63685 | DSB53DH
29143 |             | 63685 | DSB53DH
33822 |             | 63686 | TYP5873BF
33822 |             | 63686 | TYP5873BF
33822 |             | 63686 | TYP5873BF
```

Подскажите как поправить запрос, что бы притянуть колонку AttachFile и удалить дубликаты строк по post_id?

Comment: Вы бы минимально воспроизводимый пример дали, как полагается (добавьте тут код с созданием таблицы и заполнением вашими тестовыми значениями).

Comment: А таблица wp_post или типа того есть? ID, который вы хотите в результате он соответствует посту же? Что его определяет? То есть как понять, что 33590 это тот ID, а 63683 не тот?

Comment: @Сергей Все примеры указал, не нужно создавать таблицу, нужен sql запрос, всё подробно описано .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta t1
JOIN wp_postmeta t2 ON t1.post_id = t2.meta_value
JOIN wp_postmeta t3 ON t2.post_id = t3.post_id
WHERE t1.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
  AND t2.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'
  AND t3.meta_key = '_sku'
```

Конечно, вместо звёзды надо выбрать только нужные поля.

Comment: Работает идеально, то что нужно + у Вас более красивый код получился чем изначально был у меня. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил вот так.

```
select pm.post_id, pm1.meta_value _sku, pm2.meta_value _thumbnail_id, pm3.meta_value _wp_attached_file
  from `wp_postmeta` pm
  left join `wp_postmeta` pm1 on pm1.meta_key='_sku' and pm.post_id=pm1.post_id
  left join `wp_postmeta` pm2 on pm2.meta_key='_thumbnail_id' and pm.post_id=pm2.post_id
  left join `wp_postmeta` pm3 on pm3.meta_key='_wp_attached_file' and pm2.meta_value=pm3.post_id
GROUP BY pm.post_id
```

Comment: По-моему, одна копия таблицы лишняя..